# optimize query -- remove nested selects

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

How can I rewrite the query to increase performance?
Here is the query:

```
SELECT flight.*,
       DAYOFWEEK(flight.flight_time)                            AS day_of_week,
       IF(SUM(m2m_order_flights.price_gross) IS NULL, 0, SUM(
       m2m_order_flights.price_gross))                          AS sells,
       IF(flight.from_order = 0, flight.price_net * IFNULL(flight.seats, 0),
       IFNULL(SUM(m2m_order_flights.price_net), 0))             AS total_net,
       fn_getCountSold(flight.id)                               AS sold,
       fn_getCountReserved(flight.id)                           AS reserved,
       fn_getCountAvailable(flight.id, 434)                     AS available,
       IFNULL((SELECT SUM(of.price_gross)
               FROM   m2m_order_flights `of`
                      INNER JOIN `order` o
                              ON o.id = `of`.order_id
               WHERE  `of`.flight_id = flight.id
                      AND o.deleted_at IS NULL
                      AND `of`.deleted_at IS NULL), 0)          AS amount,
       (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(paid * IF(flight.currency_id =
                                    supplier_voucher.currency_id,
                                 1, (
                                         SELECT
                                                sell_rate
                                 FROM
                                                    currency_rate
                                         WHERE
                                 target_currency_id =
                                 supplier_voucher.currency_id
                                 AND base_currency_id = flight.currency_id
                                 AND current = 1
                                         LIMIT  1))), 0)
        FROM   m2m_psv_flights
               JOIN supplier_voucher
                 ON supplier_voucher.id = m2m_psv_flights.supplier_voucher_id
        WHERE  flight_id = flight.id
               AND supplier_voucher.canceled_at IS NULL
               AND supplier_voucher.deleted_at IS NULL
               AND supplier_voucher.type = 'project')
       + (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price_net), 0)
          FROM   m2m_order_flights
          WHERE  m2m_order_flights.flight_id = flight.id
                 AND m2m_order_flights.supplier_voucher_id > 0) AS psv_paid
FROM   `flight`
       LEFT JOIN `m2m_order_flights`
              ON `m2m_order_flights`.`flight_id` = `flight`.`id`
WHERE  `flight`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND `flight`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND `flight`.`project_id` = 359
       AND ( fn_isAvailableFlight(flight.id, 434) = 1 )
GROUP  BY flight.id
```

And here are the functions:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test`.`fn_getCountAvailable`(i_FlightId MEDIUMINT, i_UserId MEDIUMINT) RETURNS mediumint(9)
BEGIN
    DECLARE available_seats INT;
    DECLARE restricted_available_seats INT;
    DECLARE is_allowed INT;
    DECLARE is_admin INT;

    SET @available_seats = (IFNULL((SELECT seats FROM flight WHERE id = i_FlightId), 0) - fn_getCountSold(i_FlightId) - fn_getCountReserved(i_FlightId));

    #SET @is_admin = (SELECT 1 FROM role_user WHERE role_id = 1 AND user_id = i_UserId);

    #IF(@is_admin = 1) THEN
        RETURN @available_seats;
    #END IF;

    #SET @is_allowed = (SELECT IFNULL(1, 0) FROM role_user ru
    #                  INNER JOIN permission_role pr ON pr.role_id = ru.role_id
    #                  INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.id = pr.permission_id
    #                  WHERE user_id = i_UserId AND p.name = 'restricted_to_num_seats');

    #IF(@is_allowed = 0) THEN
    #   RETURN @available_seats;
    #END IF;

    #SET @restricted_available_seats = (SELECT `value` FROM settings WHERE `key` = 'restrict_availible_view_seats');

    #IF(@available_seats >= @restricted_available_seats) THEN
    #  RETURN @restricted_available_seats;
    #ELSE
    #  RETURN @available_seats;
    #END IF;

END;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test`.`fn_getCountReserved`(i_FlightId MEDIUMINT) RETURNS mediumint(9)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE reserved_seats INT;
    SET @reserved_seats = IFNULL((SELECT SUM(seats) FROM reserved_seats WHERE until >= current_date() AND flight_id = i_FlightId AND deleted_at is null), 0);

  RETURN @reserved_seats;

END;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test`.`fn_getCountSold`(i_FlightId MEDIUMINT) RETURNS mediumint(9)
BEGIN
    DECLARE sold_flights INT;
    SET @sold_flights = IFNULL((
              SELECT
                COUNT(*) FROM m2m_order_flights `of`
              INNER JOIN `order` o ON o.id = `of`.order_id
              WHERE `of`.flight_id = i_FlightId AND o.status_id IN(1,2,3) AND o.deleted_at is null AND `of`.deleted_at is null), 0);

  RETURN @sold_flights;

END;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test`.`fn_isAvailableFlight`(i_FlightId MEDIUMINT, i_AgentId MEDIUMINT) RETURNS tinyint(4)
BEGIN
    DECLARE has_available_flights INT;
    DECLARE flight_seats INT;
    DECLARE flight_reserved_seats INT;
    DECLARE flight_sold_seats INT;
    DECLARE agent_reserved_seats INT;

    SET @flight_seats = (SELECT seats FROM flight WHERE id = i_FlightId);
    SET @flight_reserved_seats = (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(seats), 0) FROM reserved_seats WHERE until >= current_date() AND flight_id = i_FlightId AND deleted_at IS NULL);
    SET @flight_sold_seats = (SELECT fn_getCountSold(i_FlightId));

    SET @has_available_flights = (@flight_seats - @flight_reserved_seats - @flight_sold_seats);

    IF(@has_available_flights > 0) THEN
            RETURN 1;
    END IF;

    SET @agent_reserved_seats = (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(seats), 0) FROM reserved_seats WHERE until >= current_date() AND flight_id = i_FlightId AND agent_id = i_AgentId);

    IF(@agent_reserved_seats > 0) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

END;
```

My the only attempt to optimize this was to move the `fn_isAvailableFlight` condition into `having` clause, which increased performance in about 50 times, but it's not enough.
This is the [link to mySQL dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uan-TIUsEl_28EjbUIw-S57S6JMoT9U/view?usp=sharing) for curious.

**UPDATE:**
Now, thanks to [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james), the query runs a reasonable amount of time :)

```
SELECT    flight.*,
          DAYOFWEEK(flight.flight_time)                                                                   AS day_of_week,
          IFNULL(m2m.sells,0)                                                                             AS sells,
          IF(flight.from_order = 0, flight.price_net * IFNULL(flight.seats, 0), IFNULL(m2m_total_net, 0)) AS total_net,
          IFNULL(m2m.sold,0)                                                                              AS sold,
          IFNULL(m2m.reserved,0)                                                                          AS reserved,
          (IFNULL(flight.seats,0)-IFNULL(m2m.reserved,0)-IFNULL(m2m.sold,0))                              AS available,
          IFNULL(m2m.amount,0)                                                                            AS amount,
          (
                 SELECT IFNULL(SUM(paid * IF(flight.currency_id = supplier_voucher.currency_id, 1,
                        (
                               SELECT sell_rate
                               FROM   currency_rate
                               WHERE  target_currency_id = supplier_voucher.currency_id
                               AND    base_currency_id = flight.currency_id
                               AND    CURRENT = 1
                               LIMIT  1))), 0)
                 FROM   m2m_psv_flights
                 JOIN   supplier_voucher
                 ON     supplier_voucher.id = m2m_psv_flights.supplier_voucher_id
                 WHERE  flight_id = flight.id
                 AND    supplier_voucher.canceled_at IS NULL
                 AND    supplier_voucher.deleted_at IS NULL
                 AND    supplier_voucher.type = 'project')+IFNULL(m2m.psv_paid_2,0) AS psv_paid
FROM      flight
LEFT JOIN
          (
                   SELECT   flight_id,
                            SUM(m2m_order_flights.price_gross) AS sells,
                            SUM(m2m_order_flights.price_net)   AS m2m_total_net,
                            (
                                       SELECT     COUNT(*)
                                       FROM       m2m_order_flights `of`
                                       INNER JOIN `order` o
                                       ON         o.id = `of`.order_id
                                       WHERE      `of`.flight_id = m2m_order_flights.flight_id
                                       AND        o.status_id IN(1,2,3)
                                       AND        o.deleted_at IS NULL
                                       AND        `of`.deleted_at IS NULL) AS sold,
                            (
                                   SELECT SUM(seats)
                                   FROM   reserved_seats
                                   WHERE  until >= CURRENT_DATE()
                                   AND    flight_id = m2m_order_flights.flight_id
                                   AND    deleted_at IS NULL)      AS reserved,
                            # fn_getCountAvailable(flight_id, 434) AS available,
                            (
                                       SELECT     SUM(of.price_gross)
                                       FROM       m2m_order_flights `of`
                                       INNER JOIN `order` o
                                       ON         o.id = `of`.order_id
                                       WHERE      `of`.flight_id = m2m_order_flights.flight_id
                                       AND        o.deleted_at IS NULL
                                       AND        `of`.deleted_at IS NULL) AS amount,
                            (
                                   SELECT IFNULL(SUM(seats), 0)
                                   FROM   reserved_seats
                                   WHERE  until >= CURRENT_DATE()
                                   AND    flight_id = m2m_order_flights.flight_id
                                   AND    agent_id = 434) AS agent_reserved,
                            (
                                   SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price_net), 0)
                                   FROM   m2m_order_flights `of`
                                   WHERE  m2m_order_flights.flight_id = `of`.flight_id
                                   AND    `of`.supplier_voucher_id > 0) AS psv_paid_2
                   FROM     `m2m_order_flights`
                   WHERE    m2m_order_flights.deleted_at IS NULL #WHERE fn_isAvailableFlight(flight_id, 434) = 1
                   GROUP BY flight_id) AS m2m
ON        flight.id = m2m.flight_id
WHERE     `flight`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND       `flight`.`project_id` = 359
AND       ((
                              ifnull(flight.seats,0)-ifnull(m2m.reserved,0)-ifnull(m2m.sold,0)>0)
          OR        (
                              ifnull(agent_reserved,0)>0))
```

*-- UPDATE*:
Creating indexes

```
flight (deleted_at, project_id)
supplier_voucher (canceled_at, deleted_at, `type`)
reserved_seats (flight_id, agent_id, until)
```

did speed up likely 30% but that's not enough.
`ifnull` needed for results of `left join`s.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would start by formatting the query, right now it is very difficult to see what level a certain predicate belongs to

Answer (score 1):

"explode-implode"

First it gathers all the colunns from `flights`, then joins to probably multiple rows in a second table.  This leads to duplicating all the columns in `flights`.  At then end you boil it down to exactly one copy.

SO...

1. Start by doing all the necessary sums in `m2m_order_flights`.  This should be boiled down to one row per `flight_id`.  You should not have to touch `flights` for this step.
2. *Now* `JOIN` to `flights` to grab its column *only once*.

No `GROUP BY` at the end. only in the subquery involving `m2m_order_flights`.

If that is not enough, we can look into those time-consuming procs.

**INDEXes needed**

```
INDEX(deleted_at, project_id)  -- in either order

INDEX(canceled_at, deleted_at, type)  -- in any order

INDEX(flight_id, current_id,      -- first, in either order
      until)                      -- last
```

**Possible simplifications**

Pick either 0 or NULL for various columns.  This may simplify (and speed up?) things like `ifnull(agent_reserved,0)>0))`.  Perhaps `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'` should be used (unless you need both "0" and "NULL").

This:

```
SET @x := ( SELECT foo ... );
```

can be written:

```
SELECT @x := foo ...;
```

The latter might be more efficient.  (I have no proof that it is.)

Although using @variables in a `WHERE` clause is convenient, there is some reason to believe that it is slower.

This:

```
 IF (<<boolean expression>>) THEN RETURN 1; ELSE RETURN 0; END IF;
```

can be simplified to:

```
 RETURN <<boolean expression>>;
```

This is because true==1 and false==0.

Comment: The performance is not enough, need like 150 per minute. See the update please. Thanks )

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - Check my added suggestions.